# How do you use the .addCircleLayer() in the latest Flutter Mapbox_gl version?

Tags: flutter, maps, mapbox-gl

I am making a flutter website that fetches realtime location data from my firebase database and project them in my mapbox map. I was able to deal with using `.addCircle()` to individually add them to the map but it seems like the better approach is to use `.addCircleLayer()` since I  am consistently updating multiple circles at the same time. I have searched over the internet for ways to use `.addCircleLayer()` but most of them looks outdated with methods that are no longer recognized to the current version.

Here is my code in projecting the locations **one by one**:

```
   void _projectVehiclePositions(List<VehicleData> Vehicles) {

    Vehicles.forEach((Vehicle) {
      final vehicleCircle = CircleOptions(
        geometry: LatLng(Vehicle.position.latitude, Vehicle.position.longitude),
      );
      _mapController.addCircle(vehicleCircle);
    });

   }
```

And here is my attempt to `.addCircleLayer()`:

```
 void _projectVehiclePositions(List<LatLng> VehiclePositions) {
    String sourceId = 'PositionStream';
    String layerId = 'PositionStream';
    
    _mapController.addSource(sourceId, GeojsonSourceProperties(
      data: VehiclePositions,
    ));
    
    _mapController.addCircleLayer(sourceId, layerId, const CircleLayerProperties(
      circleColor: '#E91E63',
      circleRadius: 5.0,
      circleOpacity: 0.8,
      circleStrokeColor: '#E91E63'
    ));
    
  }
```

I preprocess the data first into one List of vehicle positions before I pass it to the function responsible of adding the circle layer. So far, it doesn't work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

i've provided below code. implement accordingly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mapbox_gl/flutter_mapbox_gl.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  MapboxMapController? _mapController;
  final String accessToken =
      'MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'; // add your token key
  final LatLng initialCameraPosition = LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194); 
  final List<LatLng> vehiclePositions = [
    LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
    LatLng(37.7849, -122.4194),
    LatLng(37.7949, -122.4194),
    LatLng(37.8049, -122.4194),
    LatLng(37.8149, -122.4194),
  ];

  void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
  }

  void _addVehiclePositions(List<LatLng> positions) {
    String sourceId = 'vehiclePositions';
    String layerId = 'vehiclePositions';
    GeoJsonSource source = GeoJsonSource(sourceId, data: {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'features': positions.map((position) {
        return {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [position.longitude, position.latitude]
          }
        };
      }).toList()
    });
    CircleLayer circleLayer = CircleLayer(layerId, sourceId);
    circleLayer.circleColor = "#007cbf";
    circleLayer.circleRadius = 5;
    _mapController?.addSource(sourceId, source);
    _mapController?.addLayer(circleLayer);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map Page'),
      ),
      body: MapboxMap(
        accessToken: accessToken,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: initialCameraPosition,
          zoom: 12,
        ),
        styleString: MapboxStyles.MAPBOX_STREETS,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _addVehiclePositions(vehiclePositions);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I tried adding your `_addVehiclePositions` function but it does not recognize the GeoJsonSource class.

Comment: How to put the radius as km in the map and change the size of radius on zoom level?